# implementing unpooling layer in u-net, InvalidArgumentError is occurred

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am using EM_dataset segmentation,
keras2.3.1 and tensorflow 2,
in google colab

Here is my code. This is a U-net.

```
    def unpool(pool, ind, ksize=[1,2,2,1], scope='unpool'):

  """
  Unpooling layer after max_pool_with_argmax.
  Args:
  pool:  max pooled output tensor
  ind:   argmax indices
  ksize: ksize is the same as for the pool
  Return:
    ret: unpooling tensor
  """
  with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(scope):
    input_shape = tf.shape(pool)
    output_shape = [input_shape[0], input_shape[1] * ksize[1], input_shape[2] * ksize[2], input_shape[3]]


    flat_input_size = tf.reduce_prod(input_shape)
    flat_output_shape = [output_shape[0], output_shape[1] * output_shape[2] * output_shape[3]]

    pool_ = tf.reshape(pool, [flat_input_size])
    batch_range = tf.reshape(tf.range(tf.cast(output_shape[0], tf.int64), dtype=ind.dtype), shape=[input_shape[0], 1, 1, 1])
    b = tf.ones_like(ind) * batch_range
    b1 = tf.reshape(b, [flat_input_size, 1])
    ind_ = tf.reshape(ind, [flat_input_size, 1])
    ind_ = tf.concat([b1, ind_], 1)

    ret = tf.scatter_nd(ind_, pool_, shape=tf.cast(flat_output_shape, tf.int64))
    ret = tf.reshape(ret, output_shape)

    set_input_shape = pool.get_shape()
    set_output_shape = [set_input_shape[0], set_input_shape[1] * ksize[1], set_input_shape[2] * ksize[2], set_input_shape[3]]
    ret.set_shape(set_output_shape)
    #print(set_output_shape)
    return ret
```

also I am using ImageDataGenerator in keras

```
inputs = Input(shape=(160, 160, 1))

# encorder
c1 = layers.BatchNormalization()(inputs)
c1 = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c1)
c1 = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c1)
#p1 = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1) # 80 80
p1, argmax1 = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(input=c1, ksize=(1,2,2,1), strides=(1,2,2,1), padding='SAME')

c2 = layers.BatchNormalization()(p1)
c2 = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c2)
c2 = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c2)
#p2 = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2) # 40 40
p2, argmax2 = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(input=c2, ksize=(1,2,2,1), strides=(1,2,2,1), padding='SAME')


c3 = layers.BatchNormalization()(p2)
c3 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c3)
c3 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c3)
#p3 = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3) # 20 20
p3, argmax3 = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(input=c3, ksize=(1,2,2,1), strides=(1,2,2,1), padding='SAME')


c4 = layers.BatchNormalization()(p3)
c4 = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c4)
c4 = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c4)
#p4 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c4) # 10 10
p4, argmax4 = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(input=c4, ksize=(1,2,2,1), strides=(1,2,2,1), padding='SAME')


c5 = layers.BatchNormalization()(p4)
c5 = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c5)
c5 = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c5)
#p5 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c5) # 5 5
p5, argmax5 = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(input=c5, ksize=(1,2,2,1), strides=(1,2,2,1), padding='SAME')


c55 = layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(p5)
c55 = layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c55) 


u6 = layers.concatenate([unpool(c55, argmax5), c5])
c6 = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(u6)
c6 = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c6)

u71 = layers.concatenate([unpool(c6,argmax4), c4])
c71 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(u71)
c61 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c71)

u7 = layers.concatenate([unpool(c61,argmax3), c3])
c7 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(u7)
c7 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c7)

u8 = layers.concatenate([unpool(c7,argmax2), c2])
c8 = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(u8)
c8 = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c8)


u9 = layers.concatenate([unpool(c8,argmax1), c1], axis=3)
c9 = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(u9)
c9 = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(c9)

outputs = layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(c9)
```

Network is fine but If i do fit, Error is occured

InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 12800 values, but the requested shape has 25600
[[node functional_33/tf_op_layer_Reshape_393/Reshape_393 (defined at :4) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_56708]

I don't know why this error is occured...
please some help...

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests that it requires input image size to be 160x160 = 25600 values. but the images given input to the model aren't of the required size. you can resize all the images that are required to fit into the model to 160x160x1 and then fit them to model, it should work then.